# Proving $f: \Bbb{Z} \times\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}, \ f(a,b)=3a-2b$ is surjective without using linear diophantine equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic

I'm doing an exercise where I have to determine if

$f: \Bbb{Z} \times\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}, \ f(a,b)=3a-2b$

is injective, surjective or bijective.

Coming up with a counterexample to show that it is not injective is fairly easy. $f(2,1) = f(0,-2)$ and $(2,1)\ne(0,-2)$

Now, for the surjectivity:

**Knowing this theorem:** $\exists (a,b) \in \Bbb{Z} \times\Bbb{Z} : xa+yb = c \iff (x : y) | c$

we have $(3:2) = 1$ and $1|z \ \forall z \ \in \Bbb{Z}$ and we are done.

But in the book where I found this exercise, linear diophantine equations are introduced a few chapters after the section containing this exercise . So **I'm supposed to show the surjectivity without using the solvability of a linear diophantine equation**.

There has to be a more "basic" way of doing  this using only the following content, which is what the book covers up to the page where this exercise appears:

- Definition of a subset and basic operations between subsets (intersection, union, symmetric difference, exclusion, etc)
- Tables of truth and propositional logic
- Definition of cartesian product
- Definition of relations, reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, transitivity. Order and equivalence relations. Equivalence clases.
- Definition of a function. Injective, surjective,  and bijective  functions. Inverse functions. Composition of functions.

**How can I show that this function is surjective without using the theorem that determines whether a linear diophantine equation is solvable?**

Comment: For even integers $n=2k$, we have $f(0,-k)=n$.

For odd integers $n=2k+1$, we have $f(1,-(k-1))=n$

Comment: IMK: I find odd that your preference goes to a relatively intricate answer while another one deals with the matter in one single strike (a third proposition is even more complicated, so we can leave it rot quietly). Can you explain? For the record, the single strike approach is $$f(a,a)=a$$

Comment: @Did You are right. The answer by Redundant Aunt is much simpler. I changed my accepted answer accordingly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wanted to give another quick solution:
$$
f(a,a)=a\qquad\forall a\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
which shows surjectivity and non-injectivity (because all of $\mathbb{Z}$ is already covered by the pairs of the form $(a,a)$) at once.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be arbitrary. If $n = 2k$ for some $k$, i.e., $n$ is even, then $f(0, -k) = n$. If $n = 2k + 1$, then $n = 2(k - 1) + 3$, so $f(1, 1 - k) = n$.

Answer (score 2):

Math induction?

Base case:  $3a-2b=1\qquad \implies (a,b)=(1,1)$

Inductive Step: suppose we have an $(a_0,b_0)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $ \ \ 3a_0-2b_0=n\ \ \biggr{|} \ \exists n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Then 
$$3a_0-2b_0+(3-2)=n+(3-2)$$
$$3(a_0+1)-2(b_0+1)=n+1$$

And indeed, thanks for the comment lhf:

$$3a_0-2b_0-(3-2)=n-(3-2)$$
$$3(a_0-1)-2(b_0-1)=n-1$$

Therefore $3a-2b$ is fully onto $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You also need $n \to n-1$.

Comment: @lhf good comment.  Edited!